# Bind Output Results to Variable

Tags: output, sqldatasource, unique-id

I am using a `SQLDataSource` to insert information into a database.
While it is inserting it also grabs the `ID` of that row

```
INSERT INTO InkInventory(CodeNumber, InkType, PMS, Color, Description, PoundAvailable, Location, Supplier)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID 
VALUES (@CodeNumber, @InkType, @PMS, @Color, @Description, @PoundsAvailable, @Location, @Supplier)
```

When I use Query Builder it gives me the output perfectly, but how do I then refer to those results in my code behind, to use that number in another place?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
--Display the value of LocationID in the last row in the table.
SELECT MAX(LocationID) FROM Production.Location;
GO
INSERT INTO Production.Location (Name, CostRate, Availability, ModifiedDate)
VALUES ('Damaged Goods', 5, 2.5, GETDATE());
GO
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';
GO
--Display the value of LocationID of the newly inserted row.
SELECT MAX(LocationID) FROM Production.Location;
GO
```